# Apache Airflow task stuck in 'running'

Tags: airflow, task, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm using version `2.6.1` with a simple DAG run locally using the `SequentialExecutor` (using `airflow standalone` in the terminal). The first task runs fine since it's just a simple print statement, but the second task B gets stuck in 'running' (viewed using the UI). Looking at the terminal I don't see much happening apart from the occasional `INFO - 0 triggers currently running`.

Here's the current DAG, where only PythonOperators are used. Task 'B' uses the `geo` function, which should produce a geodataframe.

Greatly appreciated if anyone has any suggestions if there's anything wrong with the code, or some airflow configuration that needs changing:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import osmnx

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',    
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    }

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = "demo",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@once',  
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=15),
    description='demo',
    start_date = airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    )

def hello():
    print('hello')

def geo():
    print('opened')
    place = 'California, USA'
    gdf = osmnx.geocode_to_gdf(place)
    print('made a gdf')

task_a = PythonOperator(
    task_id='A',
    python_callable = hello,
    dag=dag
)

task_b = PythonOperator(
    task_id='B',
    python_callable = geo,
    dag=dag
)

task_c = PythonOperator(
    task_id='C',
    python_callable = hello,
    dag=dag
)

task_a >> task_b >> task_c
```

[image]

Comment: what do you see at "B" log ? do you see the first print 'opened' ?

Comment: Yes, when I check the log for task "B" I do see 'opened', but nothing else.

Comment: seems it stuck calling osmnx, might be big query or firewall that prevents the call, can u check this call on same computer without airflow to see if works fine ?